# ActiveRecord's joining tables and gathering info [RAILS]

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am struggling with a problem finding the way to get the data from my models.
I do have a relationship has_many through between two models. User & Event. I did the linking table because I needed additional info which will be stored in the linking table. The problem is that I am not able to get the data from the linking table.

My models are the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_users
  has_many :events, through: :event_users
end


class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :event_users
    has_many :users, through: :event_users
end
```

And the linking table:

```
class EventUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :event 
    belongs_to :user
end
```

My db schema for those models:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.text     "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.text     "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.text     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.text     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.text     "steam_id_64"
    t.text     "nick"
    t.text     "name"
    t.integer  "age"
    t.text     "country"
    t.text     "city"
    t.text     "gender"
    t.boolean  "admin"
end

create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "event_type"
    t.text     "name",           null: false
    t.datetime "starting_date"
    t.datetime "ending_date"
    t.integer  "eventable_id"
    t.text     "eventable_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
end

create_table "event_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "event_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "position"
    t.integer "score_points"
    t.text    "team_name"
    t.integer "team_score_points"
end
```

I am trying to test this through console first (I have data on the database working) I am trying to gather this data to show it on a table later.

I have tried:

```
User.joins(:events).select('*')
```

But it gives me a mix of data. But it does not give the position field located on the linking table (event_users).

I would like help if possible with the query to get the data. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want all users and all events?

Comment: No sorry, I do want the Users info, event_users info and event info.

Comment: It really depends on how you want to use it -  because you can User.all.each { |user| user.events}

Comment: I just like to gather the data to put it later on a table.

Comment: I would like to see the info from the table "event_users" as well as Users info

Comment: You'll have to ask for that explicitly, since you're using a through

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108569/discussion-between-nikos4life-and-trh).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
users = User.joins(event_users: :event)

users.select("event_users.position")
```

Comment: This gives me this error: `[145] pry(main)> users.each {|user| user.event_users.position}
NoMethodError: undefined method `position' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`

Comment: @Nikos4Life I have updated the answer, can you just give it a try.

Comment: not working :/  `[156] pry(main)> users = User.joins(event_users: :events)
=> #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x2500f8c>`

Comment: @Nikos4Life there was a typo.. `users = User.joins(event_users: :event)`  Try this

Comment: `[164] pry(main)> users = User.joins(event_users: :event)
=>   User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "event_users" ON "event_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "events" ON "events"."id" = "event_users"."event_id"
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "event_users" ON "event_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "events" ON "events"."id" = "event_users"."event_id"
[#<User:0x4bc5730`  This works but the next part does not :S

Comment: `[165] pry(main)> users.select("event_users.position")
=>   User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT event_users.position FROM "users" INNER JOIN "event_users" ON "event_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "events" ON "events"."id" = "event_users"."event_id"
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT event_users.position FROM "users" INNER JOIN "event_users" ON "event_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "events" ON "events"."id" = "event_users"."event_id"
[#<User:0x687baa8 id: nil>]
[166] pry(main)> users[1]
=> nil`